# Не работает сгенерированный IDEA код

Tags: java, intellij-idea, hashcode

Здравствуйте. Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему. Написал класс. Хочу переопределить методы equals() и hashCode(). Доверяю сгенерировать код IDEA, та это делает, но генерирует его, для себя же - нерабочим.

```
public final class ComplexNumber {
private final double re;
private final double im;

public ComplexNumber(double re, double im) {
    this.re = re;
    this.im = im;
}

public double getRe() {
    return re;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true; //(this == o) - ругается
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false; //ругается getClass() != o.getClass()


    ComplexNumber that = (ComplexNumber) o; //(ComplexNumber) o - ругается

    if (Double.compare(that.re, re) != 0) return false;
    if (Double.compare(that.im, im) != 0) return false;

    return true;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result;
    long temp;
    temp = Double.doubleToLongBits(re);
    result = (int) (temp ^ (temp >>> 32));
    temp = Double.doubleToLongBits(im);
    result = 31 * result + (int) (temp ^ (temp >>> 32));
    return result;
}

public double getIm() {
    return im;



}
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ComplexNumber a = new ComplexNumber(1, 1);
    ComplexNumber b = new ComplexNumber(1, 1);
    System.out.println(a.equals(b));
    System.out.println(a.hashCode() + " " + a.hashCode());
}}
```

Ошибки:

```
Error:(19, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

Error:(21, 18) java: incomparable types: ComplexNumber and Object

Error:(22, 37) java: incomparable types: java.lang.Class<capture#1 of ? extends ComplexNumber> and java.lang.Class<capture#2 of ? extends Object>

Error:(24, 46) java: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to ComplexNumber
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем проблема сгенерированного кода?

Comment: Вполне работоспособный код.

Comment: Текст сообщения об ошибке добавьте, код рабочий.

Comment: Ошибки добавил.

Comment: http://ideone.com/LdgQ4V

Comment: А какая версия IDEA, какая версия JDK и какой Language Level у проекта?

Comment: Если действительно не работает, то проблема может быть в компиляторе / IDE. Её давно обновляли?

Comment: IDEA 15.0.3 sdk 1.9 (java version 1.8.0.74), Lang. lavel - 8.0

Answer (score -1):

```
public static class ComplexNumber {
private double re;
private double im;

public ComplexNumber() {
}

public ComplexNumber(double re, double im) {
    this.re = re;
    this.im = im;
}

public double getRe() {
    return re;
}

public double getIm() {
    return im;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
        return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    ComplexNumber that = (ComplexNumber) o;
    return Double.compare(that.re, re) == 0 &&
            Double.compare(that.im, im) == 0;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return java.util.Objects.hash(re, im);
}
```

}

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Ваше сообщение не отвечает на вопрос, не удивляйтесь, если оно будет удалено.